# Imap gmail does not response using java SSLSocket on MAC

Tags: java, macos, imap, gmail-imap

When I executed below code on window, it runs well but Mac pc does not.

```
//declaration is removed;
    socketFactory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
        socket = (SSLSocket)socketFactory.createSocket("imap.gmail.com", 993);
        in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        output = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"));

    BufferedReader sin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    String line;
    output.println("a001 LOGIN uName pWord");//assume that uName pWord is write
    output.flush();// commit query immediately
    while ((line = sin.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
```

The message when open socket returned normaly

> - OK Gimap ready for requests from 42.118.56.137 c14mb33681806itd

but when I execute Login statement
It hang connection on without any response and never time out.
I have tried to use non secured but it did not make sense.

> Noted: 2 step verification is turn off.
>   Insecured app is enable.

Comment: Make sure you are sending \r\n, not \n end of lines.

Comment: PrintWriter.Println uses a platform specific end of line terminator. You should use some method where you control the end of lines.

Comment: U saved my day!
Thank you very much

Comment: I will add as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PrintWriter.println uses a platform specific end of line terminator, which differs between windows and mac.  IMAP requires that `\r\n` (not '\n') be sent as end of lines.  You should use some method where you control the end of lines, like:

```
output.print("a001 LOGIN uName pWord\r\n")
```